# Blackberry login design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, blackberry, authentication

I tried to look around on login design pattern in Blackberry development and ends with no result. What is the best practice for creating login form and keeping the login session? I tried to keep the login session in a Singleton but it doesn't seem to work. Eventhough I have set the singleton object as `loggedIn` but the app seems to ignore it.

This is what I come up with:

```
public class MyApp extends UiApplication
{
    private LoginContext loginContext;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyApp app = new MyApp();       
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public MyApp()
    {        
        loginContext = LoginContext.getInstance();

        if(loginContext.isLoggedIn())
            pushScreen(new HomeScreen());
        else
            pushScreen(new LoginScreen());      
    } 

    public LoginContext getLoginContext() {
        return loginContext;
    }

}
```

Does anybody have best practices, possibly with code sample, on login design patter or maybe an article on this topic that I can read?

Comment: have u tried persistence. u can save & retrieve values from it for comparison abt login sessions.btw what is LoginContext in this?

Comment: LoginContext is a singleton to keep the session

Comment: @jpartogi It would be helpful if you post the source code of the LoginContext class.